# How to release Xtext 2.13 project to Maven Central

Tags: maven, xtext, tycho

I have created an Xtext Language and I want to release it to Maven central. I have already prepared the release with:

```
mvn release:prepare
```

My first try to release with

```
mvn release:perform
```

failed due to the strict Javadoc checking (Xtext generates some tags that are not understood by the javadoc plugin). So I added this to my `pluginManagement` section, to silence the errors and convert them into warnings:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, this fails with

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.0.0:p2-metadata (attach-p2-metadata) on project com.hribol.bromium.dsl: Execution attach-p2-metadata of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.0.0:p2-metadata failed.
```

What could be the reason for this error? It happens immediately after the warnings for the Javadoc, if that matters.

EDIT: After I manually executed the steps from the Maven log, I got the full stack trace:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-
plugin:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:p2-metadata (attach-p2-metadata) on project com.hribol.bromium.dsl: Execution attach-p2-metadata of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:p2-metadata failed.: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:p2-metadata (attach-p2-metadata) on project com.hribol.bromium.dsl: Execution attach-p2-metadata of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:p2-metadata failed.
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution attach-p2-metadata of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:p2-metadata failed.
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[INFO]  ... 20 more
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.P2GeneratorImpl.getCanonicalArtifact(P2GeneratorImpl.java:193)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.P2GeneratorImpl.generateMetadata(P2GeneratorImpl.java:146)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.P2MetadataMojo.attachP2Metadata(P2MetadataMojo.java:149)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.P2MetadataMojo.execute(P2MetadataMojo.java:108)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[INFO]  ... 21 more
```

EDIT 2: After following the workaround from [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398061) - moving the tycho p2 plugin only to the projects that need it - feature, repository and target, the build no longer breaks with `IllegalArgumentException`. This time it fails in the signing phase, because a file named `p2content.xml` is missing. Does anyone know what could be the reason? If I just build the project with `mvn clean install` the `p2content.xml` is indeed created, so I think that is probably due to some wrong execution order.

Comment: maybe should run maven in debug mode to get a better error message

Comment: The release plugin runs Maven inside Maven, because it uses a tag from a repository, so I have no control over the options with which it was build, I think

Comment: Did you follow the hints on https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Workflow

Comment: Initially I did not, but even after I did now, I still get the same exception.

Comment: Hmmm have no idea.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Is the 1.1.0 version of tycho going to be released? The 1.0.0 was released in February ? Could the using of 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT be a problem?

Comment: I don’t know. I assume now that Java 9 ready oxygen available they can sort things out and prepare a new release

Comment: I guess for edit #2 the detailed error message would also be very useful

Comment: Certainly feels that this is almost done, but still can't figure out what the ordering between the phases should be.

Comment: @BernhardStadler I will upload the stack trace as soon as I can.

Comment: To me the title is misleading. It has nothing to do with deploying to Maven Central but it is a tycho-p2-plugin issue (during release only?)